# Making a Variable using "if" and working with Empty Variables

Tags: php, wordpress, attributes, shortcode, is-empty

```
<?php
// Attributes
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'postid' => '',
        'ptitle' => '',
    ), $atts )
);

$postid = $atts['postid'];
$ptitle = $atts['ptitle'];


if(!empty($ptitle)){
    echo 'Whoops! Looks like went wrong here!';
}
else
{
    if($postid == false)
    {
        echo '<span class="ptitle">$ptitle</span>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<span class="ptitle"><a href="site.com/$postid">$ptitle</a></span>';
    }
}
```

I'm trying to have my code do the following

1. Display an error message if $ptitle is empty

(This is where I need help)

2- That if another value is empty, it echo this `<span class="ptitle">$ptitle</span>`

3- If the other value ($postid) has something in it then it echoes  `<span class="ptitle"><a href="site.com/$postid">$ptitle</a></span>`

However I just don't understand enough empty values and "false" to create this correctly

Comment: You need to echo this `<span class="ptitle">$ptitle</span>` as in `echo '<span class="ptitle">$ptitle</span>';` because you're inside PHP. Then do the same for the other ones.

Comment: and this as well --  Whoops! Looks like went wrong here!

Comment: Plus, where is this being populated from `$atts`?

Comment: Ok, so the existing code, minus your additions, should give me the result i want?!!

Thats right, from $atts

<code>// Attributes
 extract( shortcode_atts(
  array(
   'postid' => '',
   'ptitle' => '',
   'pimage' => '',
  ), $atts )
 );</code>

Comment: If you want it to display if "empty", you're using the wrong method with `if(!empty($ptitle)){` you're telling it if it is NOT empty.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok so I'm doing the opposite of what I want then?! What would you recommend?

Comment: You need to do `if(empty($ptitle)){` the `!` symbol negates, it's the equivalent of `not`.

Comment: I posted my answer below. See the notes inside it http://stackoverflow.com/a/23420598/ @user51030

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to display if something is "empty", you're using the wrong method with `if(!empty($ptitle)){` you're telling it if it is NOT empty.

The `!` is a negation character which translates as `not`.

You need to use `if(empty)`

Plus, you also need to `echo` while inside PHP.

Another thing, your `$ptitle` will not echo while inside single quotes.

Use the following:

Sidenote: You may want to change `if($postid == false)` to `if($postid == true)`

```
<?php
// Attributes

    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'postid' => '',
            'ptitle' => '',
        ), $atts )
    );

$postid = $atts['postid'];
$ptitle = $atts['ptitle'];


    if(empty($ptitle)){
       echo "Whoops! Looks like went wrong here!";
       }else{ 
       if($postid == false) {
            echo "<span class=\"ptitle\">$ptitle</span>";
        } else { 
            echo "<span class=\"ptitle\"><a href=\"site.com/$postid\">$ptitle</a></span>";
        }
       }
```

You can also try:

```
<?php
// Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'postid' => '',
            'ptitle' => '',
        ), $atts )
    );

$postid = $atts['postid'];
$ptitle = $atts['ptitle'];

    if(empty($ptitle)){
       echo "Whoops! Looks like went wrong here!";
       }

       if(empty($postid)) {
            echo "<span class=\"ptitle\">$ptitle</span>";
        }

       if(!empty($postid)) { 
            echo "<span class=\"ptitle\"><a href=\"site.com/$postid\">$ptitle</a></span>";
        }
```

Comment: I know it has been a while since I asked this, but hopefully you can answer this. I noticed you added \ before the ". Can you tell me why or the name of that so I can google it?

Comment: @user51030 It's called escaping using the \ character. Sometimes it's best to have `"` to be passed in the browser. Yet, JS requires escaped `"` in an `alert` as an example. Using `'` instead of `\"` basically does the same job in PHP, but will cause an error if used in JS.

Comment: @user51030 As an added example. `echo "<span class=\"ptitle\">$ptitle</span>";` is correct, while `echo "<span class="ptitle">$ptitle</span>";` without escaping the `"` inside the already double quoted echo would throw an error. Using `echo "<span class='ptitle'>$ptitle</span>";` would not, and will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob but i think your'e missing the word **echo** before the strings you want to display and remove the *!* sign

something like this:

```
  $postid = $atts['postid'];
  $ptitle = $atts['ptitle'];


if(empty($ptitle)){
   echo "Whoops! Looks like went wrong here!"
   }else{ 
   if($postid == false) {
    echo "<span class="ptitle">$ptitle</span>"
   } else { 
    echo "<span class="ptitle"><a href=site.com/".$postid.">".$ptitle".</a></span>"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this works for you

```
if(empty($ptitle)){
    echo 'Whoops! Looks like went wrong here!';
} else if (empty($postid)) {
    echo "<span class='ptitle'>$ptitle</span>";
} else {
    echo "<span class='ptitle'><a href='site.com/$postid'>$ptitle</a></span>";
}
```